# Redirect UNIX output to append file

Tags: files, python, output

So I'm writing a Python script that passes different parameters to a Unix command and I need all of the command outputs to be saved to the same file.

However the only way I know is to re-write the file. Does anyone know how to append a file in Shell Script

Say my Unix command is:

```
Foo
```

and my operators are:

```
bar
bar1
bar2
```

The Unix command would be:

```
foo bar > output.txt
foo bar1 > output.txt
foo bar2 > output.txt
```

The contents of output.txt would only be "foo bar2"

Does anyone know how to append the file so all three command outputs will be in the output file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators)

Answer (score 3):

Each one of your three separate commands empties the `output.txt` file before writing new data to it.  This is why the file ends up only containing the data from the last command executed.

To redirect a set of commands to a file, you could use

```bsh
{
    foo bar
    foo bar1
    foo bar2
} >output.txt
```

or, on a single line,

```bsh
{ foo bar; foo bar1; foo bar2; } >output.txt
```

The curly braces defines a *compound command*. The redirection after the terminating `}` redirects *all* output of the compound command as a whole.

Since we use `>`, the file will be emptied before the output of the compound command is written to the `output.txt` file.  If you want to append to the file, use `>>` instead.

---

Another alternative:

```bsh
for operand in bar bar1 bar2; do
    foo "$operand"
done >output.txt
```

or, in a shell that has brace expansions,

```bsh
for operand in bar{,1,2}; do
    foo "$operand"
done >output.txt
```

Here, the `for` loop is a compound command that may be redirected just like the `{ ...; }` compond command above.

Again, if you want to retain the original contents of `output.txt` and only append to the file, use `>>` rather than `>` for the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

In the Unix shell the `>>` (greater greater) symbol can be used to append to a file, e.g.

```
command >> file.txt
```

Comment: Damn that was quick, Thanks for the ans

Answer (score 1):

In the last two commands, you need to use `>>` instead of `>`, which appends the content instead of completely replacing it, as `>` does.

Comment: damn that was quick, thanks for the ans

Answer (score 1):

So i literally found this minutes after posting.

The answer is to replace the `>` with `>>`

With the syntax of:

```
foo bar >> output.txt
foo bar1 >> output.txt
foo bar2 >> output.txt
```

A single `>` is to write to file.

A double `>` is to append to a file.